# django how to following relationships backwards?

Tags: python, django

I am having some issue with following relationships backwards. From the parent page i want to be able to see what children belong to that parent. Heres what i got so far

model.py

```
class Parents(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField()

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
    child_name = models.CharField()
```

views.py

```
def parents(request):
    return render_to_response('dashboard/parent.html', {'parents': Parents.objects.all() })
```

parent.html

```
{% for parent in parents %}

            <tr>
                <td><a href="/parent/get/{{ parent.id }}/">{{ parent.id }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="/parent/get/{{ parent.id }}/">{{ parant.name }}</a></td>
                <td><a href="/parent/get/{{ parent.id }}/">{{ parent.children.child_name }}</a></td>
            </tr>

            {% endfor %}

            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hint: there are multiple children for each parent.

Comment: It's very redundant to have a field named `child_name` for a model that's already named `Child`. It's better to simply call it `name`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Daniel Roseman mentioned you possibily have more than one child per parent, thus you have to get the whole set of children and iterate over it.

You can get this set with: `parent.children_set.all()`

Comment: Sorry to be a pain but this belong here '{'parents': Parents.objects.all(), 'children': Parent.children_set.all() })'.

Comment: As he has defined related name, get all children as `parent.children.all()` not `children_set.all()`.

Comment: @ChrisMeek no. Use it on the template itself - `{% foreach parent.children.all %}`.

Comment: @ChrisMeek if you don't understand the answer or it didn't help you, don't mark it as correct, and please don't open up a new one