# django referencing child in parent template

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I am trying to get a list of children that belong to a parent from the parent template.

Heres my code so far:

models.py

```
class Parent(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

    def get_child(self):
        return self.children_set.all()

class Child(models.Model):
    parent = models.ForeignKey(Parent, related_name='children')
    name = models.CharField()
```

parent.html

```
{% for parent in parents %}

        <tr>
            <td><a href="/parent/get/{{ parent.id }}/">{{ parent.id }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="/parent/get/{{ parent.id }}/">{{ parent.name }}</a></td>
            <td><a href="/parent/get/{{ parent.id }}/">{% for child in parent %} <li>{{ child.get_child.name }}</li>{% endfor %}</a></td>
        </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: [please don't repost the same question every time you hit a wall](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25846062/django-how-to-following-relationships-backwards)

Comment: Also, have you done the [django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial01/)?

Comment: @yuvi well, this is not a duplicate - here the OP is asking about getting it in the template.

Comment: @alecxe it's an **exact** duplicate. He didn't understand the previous answer and he's basically asking for the same thing. He should not mark answers as correct if he doesn't get it

Comment: @yuvi ok, this is your opinion. For a django newbie, it can be not clear how to apply the provided solution in the template.

Comment: @alecxe Exactly! If he doesn't understand an answer or it didn't work, he shouldn't mark it as correct and he definitely shouldn't ask it again.

Comment: @yuvi all I'm trying to same is that the question is related, but not the same..it is just about a different component of the MVC (or MTV) model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need `get_child()` method in `Parent`. Children of `Parent` are available as `parent.children.all()`.

Update your template as

```
<td><a href="/parent/get/{{ parent.id }}/">
   {% for child in parent.children.all %} 
      <li>{{ child.name }}
      </li>
   {% endfor %}
</a></td>
```

Comment: @yuvi, that answer is not correct. Put a comment there.

Comment: I've noticed. I'm just trying to make the OP avoid spamming the same question over and over, and instead get the answer in that original link

Comment: Thank you. I have asked it before but i couldn't make the connection. Your example made sense to me